# Morse Code Program not handling test cases with spaces

Tags: python, algorithm

I am doing this Problem set on Code Wars. I have already completed the basic Morse Code Functionality, but I am not finding ways around some other test cases.

The code tested Correct for 8/12 test cases. How can I test for a longer sentence like "The Brown Quick Fox Jumped over the lazy dog", a test case for "E E", and an test case for "S O S"?

Here is my code:

```
def decodeMorse(morse_code):    
    space_pos = morse_code.find("  ")
    match_str = ''.join(MORSE_CODE.get(i) for i in morse_code.split())        
    match_list = list(match_str)        
    if space_pos >= 0:
        edit_match = match_list.insert(int(space_pos/3.5), " ")
    final_str = ''.join(match_list)
    return final_str
```

Here is the [Code Wars Kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54b724efac3d5402db00065e) I am looking at:

> In this kata you have to write a simple Morse code decoder. While the Morse code is now mostly superseded by voice and digital data communication channels, it still has its use in some applications around the world.
>
> The Morse code encodes every character as a sequence of "dots" and "dashes". For example, the letter `A` is coded as `·−`, letter `Q` is coded as `−−·−`, and digit `1` is coded as `·−−−−`. The Morse code is case-insensitive, traditionally capital letters are used. When the message is written in Morse code, a single space is used to separate the character codes and 3 spaces are used to separate words. For example, the message `HEY JUDE` in Morse code is `···· · −·−−   ·−−− ··− −·· ·`.
>
> **NOTE:** Extra spaces before or after the code have no meaning and should be ignored.
>
> In addition to letters, digits and some punctuation, there are some special service codes, the most notorious of those is the international distress signal SOS (that was first issued by Titanic), that is coded as `···−−−···`. These special codes are treated as single special characters, and usually are transmitted as separate words.
>
> Your task is to implement a function that would take the morse code as input and return a decoded human-readable string.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> decodeMorse('.... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. .')
> #should return "HEY JUDE"
> ```
>
> **NOTE:** For coding purposes you have to use ASCII characters `.` and `-`, not Unicode characters.
>
> The Morse code table is preloaded for you as a dictionary, feel free to use it: `MORSE_CODE['.--']`

Comment: If it fails 4 test cases then it is not a working program, by definition. I don't follow the purpose of `space_pos` or the constant `3.5` in your algorithm, so it would help to edit the question to explain how you expect your solution to work.

Comment: The space_pos variable retrieves the index of double spaces before actually matching the morse code to it's alphabet values in the MORSE_CODE dictionary. I was trying to find a way to find the actual position post matching the morse_code to a string representation since the morse code takes 3 or 4 more characters to represent a single letter.

Comment: But why are you doing that? What is the significance of a double-space? Edit the question to explain how your algorithm is supposed to work.

Comment: So, I used the 3.5 as a mid point between 3 and 4 since, most morse code on average is either 3 or 4 characters long to divide space_pos and give a relative position to the initial position of the double spaces.

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything, and you need to **edit the question**.

Comment: Each Morse Code is represented as "... " for example as s. Or - - - as O. So if they're providing an input in morse code representation, they would write it as "... --- ..." for SOS, but what they do is, if they want to have a space between the letters, they put "...  ---  ..." as S O S in morse code, so I am trying to preserve the spacing in order to get the correct spacing in the human readable version, those are actually the test cases that failed, the ones with the spaces in between

Comment: Full Original Brief from CodeWars.com

Comment: In this kata you have to write a simple Morse code decoder. While the Morse code is now mostly superceded by voice and digital data communication channels, it still has its use in some applications around the world.

Comment: The Morse code encodes every character as a sequence of "dots" and "dashes". For example, the letter A is coded as ·−, letter Q is coded as −−·−, and digit 1 is coded as ·−−−−. The Morse code is case-insensitive, traditionally capital letters are used. When the message is written in Morse code, a single space is used to separate the character codes and 3 spaces are used to separate words. For example, the message HEY JUDE in Morse code is ···· · −·−−   ·−−− ··− −·· ·.

Comment: NOTE: Extra spaces before or after the code have no meaning and should be ignored.

In addition to letters, digits and some punctuation, there are some special service codes, the most notorious of those is the international distress signal SOS (that was first issued by Titanic), that is coded as ···−−−···. These special codes are treated as single special characters, and usually are transmitted as separate words.

Comment: Your task is to implement a function that would take the morse code as input and return a decoded human-readable string.

For example:

decodeMorse('.... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. .')
#should return "HEY JUDE"
NOTE: For coding purposes you have to use ASCII characters . and -, not Unicode characters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: They loaded the Dictionary with the MORSE_CODE in the boilerplate

Comment: Thank you @trinkot for the generous edits

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with `morse_code.find("  ")` you will only find the index of the first double space. There is no guarantee that your input will only contain two words. You need to also detect any other double spaces in the input string.

Secondly, dividing this position by 3.5 is unreliable to know where to insert the space in your final translated string. Although this may be a good average for the width of a letter in Morse encoding, there are words where this width is more towards 2 per letter.

You should just split the input into words by doing a `.split("  ")`. Then solve the problem for each word separately, and finally join those separate translations together with one space in between.

It is quite straightforward if you break the problem into these steps:

- translate a Morse-sentence by splitting the Morse-sentence into Morse-words (at double space boundaries) and translating each Morse-word separately
- translate a Morse-word by splitting the word into Morse-characters (at single space boundaries) and translating each Morse-character separately
- Join translated characters together
- Join translated words together, separated by spaces.

Here is a possible Python solution:

```
# helper function to solve the problem for just one Morse-word
def decodeMorseWord(morse_word):
    return "".join([MORSE_CODE[morse_letter] for morse_letter in morse_word.split(' ')])

def decodeMorse(morse_code):
    return " ".join([decodeMorseWord(morse_word) for morse_word in morse_code.split('   ')])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def decodeMorse(morse_code):
    # ToDo: Accept dots, dashes and spaces, return human-readable message
    result=[]
    final=''
    words = re.split("   ", morse_code)
    print(words)
    for w in words:
        letters=re.split(" ", w)
        alpha_word=''
        for l in letters:
            if(l!=''):
                alpha_word=alpha_word+MORSE_CODE[l]
        print(alpha_word)
        result.append(alpha_word)
    result = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', result))
    print(result)
    return (listToString(result) )


def listToString(s):  
    str1 = " " 
    return (str1.join(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def decodeMorse(morse_code):
        return ' '.join(''.join(MORSE_CODE[char] for char in word.split()) for word in morse_code.strip().split('   '))
```